# Terminology: "dimension" vs "coordinate"

Tags: terminology, coordinate-systems

"Dimension" often means the minimum number of *coordinates* needed to specify a point in *coordinate space*. In this context, a "coordinate" is a number or name referring to an axis. So we might say that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are coordinates, while $3$ is the coordinate system's dimension. But these terms are often overloaded.

For example, people often say things such as the "$x$ dimension". Here "dimension" is the same as "coordinate": it is an axis rather than the minimum number of coordinates. And people often refer to objects such as $(1, -10, 7)$ as "coordinates". Here, a "coordinate" is no longer an axis but a tuple. Furthermore, people might even refer to a single value in a tuple as a "coordinate", e.g. "In $(10, 5)$, the $x$-coordinate is $10$".

So my questions are:

- Is a "dimension" a number or an axis or both depending on context?
- Is a "coordinate" an axis, a tuple, or a single value from the tuple?

Comment: Could you make an example of this improper use?

Comment: Which usage do you consider improper?

Comment: I was asking for an example of the usages you mention in your second paragraph.

Comment: In the second paragraph, I write things like "For example, people often say things..." and "And people often refer to..." These are not examples?

Comment: I was hoping for a full sentence (possibly also with some context, or a source).

Comment: I just googled for "y dimension" and found [this](https://oip.manual.canon/USRMA-0935-zv-CS-enUV/contents/PS8505_prset_0051.html): "This setting enables you to specify the Y dimension of the custom paper. The Y dimension can be adjusted in increments of 0.1 mm from 100.0 mm through 297.0 mm." And [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m309-03a/a1/alo/WavesHigher.html) is an example from a mathematical source: "This is the same as in 1D case, but with an extra factor for the y-dimension." I can add more examples later, but I think these kinds of usages are fairly common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each word to have just one meaning, use *dimension* only for the cardinality of a basis of the vector space, i.e. a number of Cartesian coordinates needed to specify a point, and *coordinate* for one of the numbers used in such a specification. An *axis* is then a locus of all but one of the coordinates being zero, e.g. $y=z=0$ is the $x$-axis in one parametrization of $3$-dimensional space. All the numbers as a tuple would be the point's *coordinates*. A "coordinate" definitely shouldn't mean an axis.

However, there is one downside to the above approach. How do you refer to a locus of the form $y=a,\,z=b$ for $a,\,b$ not both $0$? I don't think anyone has a name for these; we just say such lines are parallel to the $x$-axis. When people talk of the $x$-dimension, they probably want to compare points differing only in $x$ (i.e. lying on such a line), or to talk about what happens as you move along such a line. It's probably best to talk just about varying $x$.

Answer (score 1):

A *dimension* is almost always a number. It literally means measurement, so it's easy to see why we may also use it synonymously with *coordinate.* Thus, usually, a coordinate is also a number.

However, in some situations where an object is more properly "measured" by vectors (or even other objects) instead of just numbers, we may by analogy refer to each of the vectors defining this objects as the coordinates or dimensions of the object.